# Unity Client not connecting to host

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

I'm trying to connect a network client to a host using unity but I'm getting false returned through the debug check `Debug.Log(myClient.isConnected.ToString());`. I'm creating a new client and connecting with the method `setupClient()` but I guess I'm doing something incorrectly. How can I fix this? Am I debugging this correctly?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkSystem;

public class MyMsgType
{
    public static short texture = MsgType.Highest + 1;
};

//Create a class that holds a variables to send
public class TextureMessage : MessageBase
{
    public byte[] textureBytes;
    public string message = "Test Received Message"; //Optional
}

public class UNETChat : Chat
{
    NetworkClient myClient;
    public Texture2D previewTexture;
    string messageToSend = "Screen Short Image";

    private void Start()
    {
        //if the client is also the server
        if (NetworkServer.active) 
        {
            // Register to connect event
            myClient.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Connect, OnConnected);
            // Register to texture receive event
            myClient.RegisterHandler(MyMsgType.texture, OnTextureReceive);
        }
        setupClient();
    }

    public void DoSendTexture()
    {
        StartCoroutine(TakeSnapshot(Screen.width, Screen.height));
    }

    WaitForEndOfFrame frameEnd = new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    public IEnumerator TakeSnapshot(int width, int height)
    {
        yield return frameEnd;

        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(800, 800, TextureFormat.RGB24, true);
        texture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, 800, 800), 0, 0);
        texture.LoadRawTextureData(texture.GetRawTextureData());
        texture.Apply();

        Debug.Log("Texture size is : " + texture.EncodeToPNG().Length);

        sendTexture(texture, messageToSend);

        // gameObject.renderer.material.mainTexture = TakeSnapshot;
    }

    //Call to send the Texture and a simple string message
    public void sendTexture(Texture2D texture, string message)
    {
        TextureMessage msg = new TextureMessage();

        //Convert Texture2D to byte array
        msg.textureBytes = texture.GetRawTextureData();
        msg.message = message;

        NetworkServer.SendToAll(MyMsgType.texture, msg);

        Debug.Log("Texture Sent!!");
    }

    // Create a client and connect to the server port
    public void setupClient()
    {
        Debug.Log("Setup Client");
        //Create new client
        myClient = new NetworkClient();
        //Register to connect event
        myClient.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Connect, OnConnected);
        //Register to texture receive event
        myClient.RegisterHandler(MyMsgType.texture, OnTextureReceive);
        //Connect to server
        myClient.Connect("localhost", 4444);

        Debug.Log(myClient.isConnected.ToString());
    }

    //Called when texture is received
    public void OnTextureReceive(NetworkMessage netMsg)
    {
        TextureMessage msg = netMsg.ReadMessage<TextureMessage>();

        //Your Received message
        string message = msg.message;

        Debug.Log("Texture Messsage " + message);

        //Your Received Texture2D
        Texture2D receivedtexture = new Texture2D(4, 4);
        receivedtexture.LoadRawTextureData(msg.textureBytes);
        receivedtexture.Apply();
    }

    public void OnConnected(NetworkMessage netMsg)
    {
        Debug.Log("Connected to server");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I debugging this correctly?

No, and you are not using `NetworkClient.isConnected` correctly.

The [`NetworkClient.Connect`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkClient.Connect.html) function is asynchronous which means that when you call it, it does not wait or block for that connection to actually connect. It uses a Thread to do the connection and when you use `NetworkClient.isConnected` right after calling `NetworkClient.Connect`, you will get unexpected result.

`NetworkClient` notifies you with a callback function when it is connected. The callback function is registered with the `NetworkClient.RegisterHandler` and `MsgType.Connect`. In your case, it is registered to the `OnConnected` function so `OnConnected` should be called when you are connected to the network.

You either have to start a coroutine and use `NetworkClient.isConnected` inside that coroutine function to wait for the connection like this:

```
while(!NetworkClient.isConnected)
{
    Debug.Log("Waiting for Connection");
    yield return null;
}
Debug.Log("Connected");
```

or use the callback function (`OnConnected`) to detect when the client is connected.

---

Unrelated but it would be extremely useful to also subscribe to Error and Disconnect events too. These are important when troubleshooting your network code.

```
myClient.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Error, OnError);
myClient.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Disconnect, OnDisconnect);
```

...

```
private void OnError(NetworkMessage netMsg)
{
    ErrorMessage error = netMsg.ReadMessage<ErrorMessage>();
    Debug.Log("Error while connecting: " + error.errorCode);
}

private void OnDisconnect(NetworkMessage netMsg)
{
    ErrorMessage error = netMsg.ReadMessage<ErrorMessage>();
    Debug.Log("Disconnected: " + error.errorCode);
}
```